# VESA driver doesn't work in TrueOS (FreeBSD 12)

Tags: drivers, freebsd, intel, trueos

I'm using TrueOS (FreeBSD12 current) in my hard disk.
when it start after installed it. it suggest VESA to install but when i choise the vesa drive the screen changed to white , i rebooted and changed the driver to intel and it done but the backlight dosn't well i think the driver not well.
How I can download the suggested driver vesa and use it.

I'm using grub2 and dual-booting TrueOS with a arch and fedora.
My `lspci` output in Arch is:

```
$ lspci 
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family KT Controller (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation QM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd PCIe SDXC/MMC Host Controller (rev 07)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak] (rev 34)
```

i heared that linux driver maybe using , how i can do that.

Comment: i'm new in freebsd world i have freebsd 10 in  virtualbox in arch and dual boot with TrueOS ( FreeBSD 12 current ).

Comment: I couldn't fix all of your question, because there was one part that I simply could not make head nor tail of.  You also need to explain what is doing the suggestion here, and why you think that there isn't a VESA driver in the box.

Comment: @JdeBP sorry but there are some missing words when i edited the post . i added them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the scfb driver instead.

As in `/usr/local/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/xorg.conf`:

```
Section "Device"
    Driver      "scfb"
EndSection
```

From https://wiki.freebsd.org/Graphics/SCFB

> If an accelerated graphics driver is not available for your FreeBSD
>   system, an alternative is to use the scfb driver. At the time of
>   writing, this is a common option for laptops with Broadwell or Skylake
>   chipsets from Intel with integrated graphics, until the Intel DRM
>   driver is updated to include support. Whilst the scfb driver does not
>   provide accelerated graphics, and is missing some features like
>   brightness adjustment and support for external displays, it works fine
>   on built-in laptop displays for simple desktop use and even playing
>   videos.
>
> The system must be using the new vt(4) (aka Newcons) console for the
>   scfb driver to work. This is the default if the system was booted with
>   UEFI, but not if it was booted using (legacy) BIOS mode. Some laptops
>   must be booted using UEFI mode for the scfb driver to work (booting in
>   legacy BIOS mode but with that sysctl manually set to use vt(4) may
>   not work).

Comment: thanx @Rui F Ribeiro i'll tray this solution in freebsd 11  if i face the same porblem coz now i remove TrueOs and install freebsd 11. thanx for helping